# Slim not recognising that route is actually a subdirectory: Throwing 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I have a folder structure like this

```
assets/
clients/
- assets/
- includes/
- .htaccess
- index.php
includes/
vendor/
views/
.htaccess
index.php
```

And slim works normally for that route folder, yet if I go to **myroot.com/clients** expecting it to not be controlled by slim, my root folder's slim throws a 404 page.

Weirdly though when I go to **myroot.com/includes** it does treat it like a subdirectory and lists the files in the includes.

This is all thats in the root .htaccess in case it helps

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Also it should be noted that clients is NOT using Slim, just vanilla php

EDIT: The slim route that im sure is causing the problem

I basically have a 'catch all' route at the bottom of all my named routes, so that I dont have to create a new route for each standard page template I create. But I though slim would still cancel this route if the url was a directory?

```
$app->get('/:page', function ($page) use ($app) {
    $route = $app->router->getNamedRoute('standardRoute');
    $route->setParams(['page'=> $page,'subpage'=> ""]);
    $result = $route->dispatch();
});
$app->get('/:page/:subpage', function ($page,$subpage) use ($app) {
    $arr = $app->engine->returnData();
    $p = new JTProject();
    $projects = $p->projectList();

    $arr['projectlist'] = $projects;

    JtUtils::renderTemplate($app,$page."/".$subpage,$arr);
})->name('standardRoute');
```

Comment: Does  http://myroot.com/clients/ work and do you get the 404 page from Slim or webserver?

Comment: Also the .htaccess file does not look like it belongs to Slim http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/

Comment: Sorry I stupidly put the wrong .htaccess file contents up, but it seems like theyre still not the same as what slim says to use. Thanks for the link I'll try that out.

Comment: But also in answer to your first question, the 404 page comes from slim, not the webserver

Comment: Can you add your Slim routes?

Comment: I just added the root that I'm sure is whats causing the issue. In my utils function of render template it checks if its a real template and pushes a 404 if not. But I thought slim and the .htaccess would not even get that far if the URL pointed to a directory?

Comment: Since the .htaccess's `!-d` condition prevents all existing directories from being rewritten, I'm assuming it's the clients/index.php that actually throws 404 error somehow.

Comment: Why do you have more than one .htaccess file? Are you exposing more than one folder as web root?